# Нужно вывести char_concat("abcdef") == 'af1be2cd3' , а у меня "af3be2cd1". Не могу сообразить

Tags: python

```
def char_concat(s):
    if len(s) % 2 == 1:
        s.replace(s[len(s) // 2], '')
    i = len(s) // 2

    if len(s) == 2:
       return s + str(i)
    return s[0] + s[-1] + str(i) + char_concat(s[1:-1])

print(char_concat("abcdef"))
```

Comment: На прошлые ваши вопросы есть ответы, но ни один не принят. Ознакомьтесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подумайте, откуда на третьем уровни рекурсии функция может знать, что он третий? Ниоткуда, если вы такую информацию не передадите. Поэтому добавляем параметр и избавляемся от уже ненужного i.

```
def char_concat(s, level=1):
    return s[0] + s[-1] + str(level) + char_concat(s[1:-1], level+1) if len(s) > 1 else ""

print(char_concat("abcdef"))
print(char_concat("abcdefghi"))

af1be2cd3
ai1bh2cg3df4
```

Ну правда, если подумать, то можно строку обходить из середины, тогда окончание рекурсии естественное по уменьшению длины, только новую строку неуклюже собирать приходится

```
def char_concat(s):
    i = len(s) // 2
    return char_concat(s[:i-1]+s[len(s)-i+1:]) + s[i-1] + s[len(s)-i] + str(i) if i else ""
```

Функцию, кстати, можно реализовать и без рекурсии.

```
def char_concat1(s):
    return ''.join([s[i] + s[len(s)-1-i] + str(i+1)  for i in range(len(s)//2)])
```

Comment: Огромное  спасибо